# Replacing the title of a question to show up the technical aspect

Tags: discussion, questions, rejected-edits, title

I suggested this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21257096), which replaces the question title:

> Don't display an empty folder in a table

By:

> Conditional skipping of a row while displaying a table

I wanted to make this post more useful, for example if a beginner is looking through a search engine how to skip the current iteration and go to the next one.

I got one rejection for this reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I'm not sure to understand where there is a deviation here. Moreover, did I make a mistake by rephrasing it more generically with technical terms?

Comment: Only one reviewer rejected your edit. The other reviewer approved it and removed a tag (I guess by using the "Improve Edit" option). So, everything is fine.

Comment: Seems appropriate to me, this question is about folders and not database rows.

Comment: @HansPassant I wasn't talking about _database_ tables.

Comment: This isn't about what you talked about, it is what the Googlers will read.  "row" and "table" in the title => must be a database question.

Comment: You did the right thing. Many of the edits I make to questions are like this. Very few are rolled back.